# Azure ARM template for continuous resource adding

Tags: azure, templates, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'd like to clarify the following gap regarding Azure ARM templates:
Let's suggest I have a master template with the following inside:

```
App Service plan creation
Azure SQL server creation
SQL elastic pool creation (using previously created Azure SQL server)
```

This template will be used for the initial creation of my cloud infrastructure.

Next, I will add a child (nested or linked) template to my master template.
The child template will contain the AppService Web App+SQL creation:

```
Web App creation (using App Service Plan defined in master template)
Azure SQL database creation (using Azure SQL server defined in master template)
Adding Azure SQL database to elastic pool (defined in master template)
```

I will omit several details like the initial creation of the Azure Key Vault and creation and store in this vault required credentials like SQL admin username\password or SSL certificates for my Web App.

So, what I want to have at the end of the template deployment execution is:
`first template deployment`

- Creation of basic infrastructure (app service plan for web apps, SQL server added to elastic pool)
- A single instance of an app service (web app+SQL) using previously created app service plan and elastic pool (where my SQL database will be placed)

`second template deployment`

- A single (second) instance of an app service (web app+SQL) will be created using the existing infrastructure

`N-template deployment`

- A single (N-instance) of an app service (web app+SQL) will be deployed <...>

The questions are:

- Should I use nested or linked templates? What's the exact difference in my case?
- Is my overall solution correct or should I modify it\find another approach?

I've already found the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016892/azure-do-not-allow-arm-template-to-modify-existing-resources) saying, for example, I can use resource lock (to prevent deletion) or use incremental mode for deployment (to keep existing resources) however, this doesn't answer my question regarding the entire approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested\Linked template can be used interchangeably. Its the same thing. One might argue that nested templates are inline templates and linked are actually linked, but it doesnt really matter, both are the same thing (they are implemented in the template slightly differently, but the result is the same). Child templates (and this is really how you want to call those).

As for the actual questions:

1. Why do you want to use child templates at all? I dont see a use case for those.
2. I dont see anything wrong with the approach, apart from using child templates just for the sake of using them.

If you want your approach to be "modular" (hence child template usage) you could as well use configuration and implementation separation to achieve the result ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) method).

Comment: Sounds quite ambiguous. Could you please be more precise about the templates? Because I need first create my cloud infrastructure and then constantly deploy web apps, hence I can't protect my initial resources as they aren't created at all. Suggested "DRY" approach means I should separate my templates - one for infrastructure and second for my continuous deployments so it differs from Microsoft's [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates) - break down the solution into components and reuse templates <...>.

Comment: well, you see, your question is about as close as it gets to a bad one. because there can be no real answer to your question. its a matter of preference. `I can't protect my initial resources as they aren't created at all.` you dont need to protect them. Just use incremental mode (which is the default anyway). If you only need to deploy web apps after deploying initial template créate a separate template only for webapps and use that to deploy new webapps.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Thanks.